# How do I fix an xCode (12.5.1) Undefined symbols for architecture arm64?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, frameworks, linker-errors

I hope you can help!

I am building an iOS app in xCode 12 and under unity framework I am getting the following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"__SaveImage", referenced from:
_CallNative__SaveImage_m639032311A61B9B0FB248AFB17B761C6243BE96F in CallNative.o
_CallNative_SaveImageToCameraRoll_mC1241163746E2650CCCBF5F2E32BFA0CAC4529AC in CallNative.o
(maybe you meant: _CallNative__SaveImage_m639032311A61B9B0FB248AFB17B761C6243BE96F)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Enable Bitcode is set to 'No'

Build active architectures = No

I have tried linking different frameworks, but nothing worked yet.

All assistance greatly appreciated.
E

Comment: Looks like you have a native plugin in your unity project, that was compiled without 64bit support. You need a new version that was compiled with arm64 architecture.

Comment: Thanks @JeanLuc. Appreciated. I believe all was compiled with arm64, but I will try again. Thanks.